# Did Michael Jeffery (Hendrix's manager) kill Jimi Hendrix after tricking him into signing an insurance policy?

Tags: criminology, music

[Michael Jeffery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Jeffery_(manager)), Jimi Hendrix's manager, tricked Hendrix into signing an insurance contract that pays Jeffery $2 million upon the death of Mr James Marshall Hendrix.
A short time later, Hendrix is found "drowned with wine in his lungs and undigested sleeping pills in his stomach".

There's even a claim about it in [this article](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/people/news/hendrix-murdered-by-his-manager-says-former-aide-1693583.html):

> ### Hendrix murdered by his manager, says former aide
>
> The rock legend Jimi Hendrix was murdered by his manager, who stood to collect millions of dollars on the star's life insurance policy, a former roadie has claimed in a new book.
>
> James "Tappy" Wright says that Hendrix's manager, Michael Jeffrey, drunkenly confessed to killing him by stuffing pills into his mouth and washing them down with several bottles of red wine because he feared Hendrix intended to dump him for a new manager, according to a report in the Mail on Sunday.
>
> In his book, Rock Roadie, Mr Wright says Jeffrey told him in 1971 that Hendrix had been "worth more to him dead than alive" as he had taken out a life insurance policy on the musician worth $2m (about £1.2m at the time), with himself as the beneficiary. Two years later, Jeffrey was killed in a plane crash.

So is this true?

Comment: I guess, but it would be nice for some kind of statement made, just to let everyone know Hendrix didn't die of a drug overdose, and to remind everyone to be very careful when signing anything.

Comment: We'll probably never know - but it's a good way to sell a book ;-) http://www.independent.co.uk/news/people/news/hendrix-murdered-by-his-manager-says-former-aide-1693583.html

http://www.amazon.com/Rock-Roadie-Backstage-Confidential-All-star/dp/1906779066

Comment: I always thought it was the EMTs that killed him.  He was alive and conscious when they arrived, he was placed on a gurney *on his back* (which you wouldn't do with an OD victim) and died choking on his own vomit.

Comment: @JohnnyBones - Yes you would. If the victim is alive and conscious, transporting on his back/position of comfort is fine for an OD victim. BLS protocol is lying in a left lateral position for *unconscious* patients. ALS has different interventions such as intubation that would allow recumbent transport.

Comment: @JohnP: But was this the case in 1970?